# How can I get this footer to finally do what I want? Would love some advice

Tags: html, wordpress, css

When I do something like this for the footer css

```
footer {
position: fixed;
top:800px;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:80px;
}
```

When I resize the browser window from the bottom upward, of course, the footer does not move and does not overlap my main content which is great however, when viewing the site at different screen sizes, the footer being a fixed footer of course is at the bottom for some screen sizes then larger sizes it isn't at the bottom of course because it's fixed. So ultimately what would I would love to have is a footer like this:

```
footer {
position: fixed;
top:90%;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:80px;
}
```

Which creates a footer that stays at the bottom of the page regardless of resizing yet it can overlap content. I want to have a fixed footer that will always stay at the bottom yet never overlap content.

I could use media queries for popular sizes but of course at some sizes it won't work out. 
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Providing a link to a test site or a JSFiddle would increase the odds of someone answering your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
}
```

Then give your content a bottom padding of at least 80px. Why are you using top anyhow?

Comment: you should link to your site or some place to demonstrate. this definitely works. If it doesn't then there are other factors either not applied or conflicting